# Conjunction reduction : your address and phone number / your father and your elder brother

Tags: conjunction-reduction

> How is that you didn't tell us even about your address and phone number ?
>
> Are not your father and your brother out of town ?

Why is that we have used *your* just once in first sentence and twice in second sentence ? Will the sentence be still grammatical and correct if one uses *your* vice versa i.e. twice in first sentence and once in second one ?

Comment: You should use *aren't* instead of *are not*.

Comment: @user3169 I think 'about' in first example could also be omitted, what do you say ?

Comment: *about* adds some context, information *about* your address and phone number (maybe it changed), rather than just telling you the information. So it depends on context. Actually I think *even* is out of place. If it is necessary, "How is **it** that you didn't *even* tell us about your address and phone number ?" would be better.

Answer (score 2):

It is equally correct to say

> Your address and phone number

and

> Your address and your phone number

Similarly,

> Your father and your brother

and

> Your father and brother

are both correct. The only time someone may find it difficult to understand what you're saying is when both nouns could be referring to the same entity. The following sentences illustrate this point:

> My uncle and mentor was a good man. (The same person was my uncle and my mentor)
>
> My uncle and my mentor were proud of me. (Two separate people were my uncle and my mentor)

In general, using "my" before both nouns is used to avoid confusion, although this is not required. In my example, "my uncle and mentor" could also refer to two separate people, just as "my uncle and my mentor" could still refer to one person. This distinction should be clarified in the rest of the sentence.